# C program with forks only prints output if I don't use wait()

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, exec

I'm writing some programs in C to learn about child processes and I'm having a little trouble with the code below. The idea is to simulate bash commands with pipes using exec, unnamed pipes and copy2, but somehow the program only seems to work if I remove the second and third wait(NULL)

```
int pipe_fd[2][2];
enum {READ, WRITE};
void ls() {
    close(pipe_fd[0][READ]);
    dup2(pipe_fd[0][WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL);
}

void grep() {

    close(pipe_fd[0][WRITE]);
    close(pipe_fd[1][READ]);
    dup2(pipe_fd[0][READ], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(pipe_fd[1][WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp("grep", "grep", "e", NULL);
}

void wc() {
    close(pipe_fd[1][WRITE]);
    dup2(pipe_fd[1][READ], STDIN_FILENO);
    execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pipe(pipe_fd[0]);
    pipe(pipe_fd[1]);
    pid_t pid_ls = fork();
    if (pid_ls < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else if (pid_ls == 0) ls();
    wait(NULL);
    
    pid_t pid_grep = fork();
    if (pid_grep < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else if (pid_grep == 0) grep();
    wait(NULL);
    close(pipe_fd[0][WRITE]);
    close(pipe_fd[0][READ]);
    
    
    pid_t pid_wc = fork();
    if (pid_wc < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else if (pid_wc == 0) wc();
    wait(NULL);
    close(pipe_fd[1][WRITE]);
    close(pipe_fd[1][READ]);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what might be the problem. I'm pretty sure I still need to wait() even after running exec()

Comment: Exec all the commands, then wait for 3 processes to return at the end. The `grep` command is waiting until there is no more input, which it detects when the output of `ls` closes the write end of the pipe.

Comment: *even after running exec()* - If `exec()` is successful, then it does not return, so there is no "after running exec()". So theoretically your `wait()` is only being run by the parent, which is fine. Yet, you never make sure it is successful, so it might be a problem.

Comment: You could also close the file descriptors that you don't need, including those you've `dup2`d. Also wait for _all_ your children and make sure you _never_ return from a function calling `exec*`. If `exec*` fails, call `exit(1)`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/3G7fb8ds3)

Comment: @jxh I think that worked, thank you! I'm not sure I get it though, shouldn't ls close the write end of its pipe as soon as the process finishes running?

Comment: @Davidbowie123 yeah but your parent process will still have it open.

Comment: @Davidbowie123 What Ted said.

Answer (score 0):

Opening your pipes ahead of time means that, until you close the pipes, every child is going to receive a copy of every single open file descriptor (either open end of a pipe).

Each child must then close every single file descriptor it is not using, or the other end of that pipe will stay open causing processes that *are* using that particular pair of descriptors to block, waiting for more data.

You must also close the *old* file descriptor given to `dup2` (the first argument), otherwise both it and the *new* file descriptor (the second argument) will be open, pointing to the same file description.

You should *reap* your child processes after additionally closing all the pipes in the parent process.

More completely (although skipping some error handling for brevity):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void open_all_these_pipes(size_t n, int pipes[n][2])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pipe(pipes[i]);
}

void close_all_these_pipes(size_t n, int pipes[n][2])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }
}

pid_t spawn_child(size_t n, int pipes[n][2], int read_from, int write_to, char * const * argv)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (0 == pid) {
        if (-1 != read_from)
            dup2(pipes[read_from][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        if (-1 != write_to)
            dup2(pipes[write_to][1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        close_all_these_pipes(n, pipes);

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return pid;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ls[] = { "ls", "-al", NULL };
    char *grep[] = { "grep", "e", NULL };
    char *wc[] = { "wc", "-l", NULL };

    int pipes[2][2];
    open_all_these_pipes(2, pipes);

    spawn_child(2, pipes, -1, 0, ls);
    spawn_child(2, pipes, 0, 1, grep);
    spawn_child(2, pipes, 1, -1, wc);

    close_all_these_pipes(2, pipes);

    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    while ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child %ld exited with status %d.\n", (long) pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

```
$ ls -al | grep e | wc -l
19
$ ./a.out 
19
Child 70609 exited with status 0.
Child 70610 exited with status 0.
Child 70611 exited with status 0.
```