# Reading from pipe in C always returns 0 despite different values being written

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, ipc

I'm writing a program that takes the following input: An integer n that represents the number of processes to create, another integer c which represents an initial value, and a final integer s which is the first process. The code works in the following way: The parent process initializes all child processes and sends c to the °sth process. s uses it to produce a secret number, and sends it to the next child process. Each child process then receives the number from the previous process and sends it +1 to the next one. The program ends when s receives an integer which is larger than its own secret number, after which it sends the result to the parent process.

However in my code, the pipe to ensue this communication doesn't seem to work. For some reason, after I write the result to the parent process, it does not actually read anything.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "constants.h"
#include <signal.h> 

int n;
int generate_random_number(){
    return (rand() % 50);
}

void close_all_pipes(int pipe_fd[][2], int i) {
    //Coses all pipes if i isn't in range, otherwise closes all the process won't use
    int prev = (i >= 0 && i < n) ? (i-1+n) % n : i;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (j != prev) {
            close(pipe_fd[prev][PIPE_WRITE]);
        }
        if (j != i) {
            close(pipe_fd[i][PIPE_READ]);
        }
    }
}

void hijo_favorito(int i, int buffer, int pipe_fd[][2]) {
    int numero_secreto = buffer - 1;
    do {
        numero_secreto = generate_random_number();
    } while(numero_secreto <= buffer);
    close(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_READ]);
    close_all_pipes(pipe_fd, i);
    int num = buffer;
    write(pipe_fd[i][PIPE_WRITE], &num, sizeof(num));
    while(1) {
        read(pipe_fd[(i-1 + n) % n][PIPE_READ], &num, sizeof(num));
        if (num > numero_secreto) {
            printf("Num: %d\n", num); //for debugging purposes
            write(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_WRITE], &num, sizeof(num));
            close(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_WRITE]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        num++;
        write(pipe_fd[i % n][PIPE_WRITE], &num, sizeof(num));
    }
}

void hijo_standard(int i, int pipe_fd[][2]) {
    close_all_pipes(pipe_fd, i);
    close(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_READ]);
    close(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_WRITE]);
    int num;
    while(1) {
        read(pipe_fd[(i-1 + n) % n][PIPE_READ], &num, sizeof(num));
        num++;
        write(pipe_fd[i][PIPE_WRITE], &num, sizeof(num));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    //Funcion para cargar nueva semilla para el numero aleatorio
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    int status, pid, start, buffer;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    buffer = atoi(argv[2]);
    start = atoi(argv[3]);

    if (argc != 4){ printf("Uso: anillo <n> <c> <s> \n"); exit(0);}
    if (start < 0 | start >= n) {printf("Proceso inicial inválido.\n"); exit(0);}
    
    printf("Se crearán %i procesos, se enviará el caracter %i desde proceso %i \n", n, buffer, start);
    pid_t *children = malloc(sizeof(*children) * n);
    
    int pipe_fd[n+1][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) pipe(pipe_fd[i]);
    close(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_WRITE]);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == start) {
            children[i] = fork();
            if (children[i] < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            else if (children[i] == 0) hijo_favorito(i, buffer, pipe_fd);
        }
        else {
            children[i] = fork();
            if (children[i] < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            else if (children[i] == 0) hijo_standard(i, pipe_fd);
        }
    }
    int res;
    sleep(1); //sync time
    read(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_READ], &res, sizeof(res));
    printf("El número final es: %d\n", res);
    close(pipe_fd[n][PIPE_READ]);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {if (i != start) kill(children[i], SIGKILL);};
    close_all_pipes(pipe_fd, n+1);
    free(children);
}
```

Comment: Calling `close` immediately after `pipe` is surely wrong.

Comment: As Ben says, it looks like you are closing the write end of the pipe the parent plans to read from, but in doing so that file descriptor is also closed in the child that eventually needs to write to it. I feel like you possibly misunderstood my [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77048057/2505965) on yesterday's question about when it is the appropriate time to close file descriptors.

Comment: Re "*doesn't seem to work*", Maybe you should start by checking what error is returned! It makes no sense to call `read` and `write` without checking the result. `read` isn't guaranteed to read as much as requested, and `write` isn't guaranteed to write as much as requested. And they frequently don't.

Comment: Also, be aware `atoi()` provides *zero* error checking on the input. It will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");` and silently return `0` without any indication of an error. While fine for short personal test programs, you will want to use `strtol()` or at least `sscanf()` to do the conversion so you have some indication of whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *It will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");` and silently return `0` without any indication of an error.*  [Oh, it's much worse than that](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1p1): "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ooof... very good addition. `"my cow" != 0 => UB`...